# Resistance to electric current in conductors

Tags: electronics

Why does the resistance to electric current increases in a conductor when the temperature is increased?

Comment: Just google [Why does electrical resistance increase with temperature](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+does+electrical+resistance+increase+with+temperature).

Answer (score 1):

Increased temperature means increased random motion of the atoms making up the conductor. Resistance is due to scattering of conduction electrons by disorder  .